# Get single column from store procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am a quite new on high level store procedures and i am stack on something. Let me tell you about my problem. I have a receipt data and this receipt has created time and pendingDated. My aim is that to substract forwardDate from getdate to find pending date and if pendingdays drops (-) value then cancel the invoice receipt.

Here is my store procedure:

```
USE [europrotel]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [europroteluser].[SPEP_SENDEFATURAINVOICETODAY]    Script Date: 
09/12/2020 08:58:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [europroteluser].[SPEP_SENDEFATURAINVOICETODAY] AS
declare  @tarih datetime,@mpehotel int, @forwardDate int

select @mpehotel = 1  
set @tarih =  CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
set @forwardDate =7

select 
  'Normal' Tur, 
  r.datum Tarih,
  r.rechnr FaturaNo, 
  r.name FaturaUnvani, 
--r.resno RezNo, r.kdnr MisafirId, 
  r.sum_belast Tutar, 
  r.Ref, 
  MAX(E.CREATEDDATE) GonderimTarihi, 
  MAX(E.CREATEDTIME) GonderimSaati, 
  MAX(E.PDFPATH) PdfFatura,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EARSIVFATURALOG WHERE INVOICEREF = r.REF AND ISVOIDINVOICE = 0) Deneme,
  MAX(E.INVOICESTATUS) GonderimMesaji,
  ISNULL(MAX(E.FATDURUM), 0) FATDURUM, 
  ISNULL(MAX(E.FATDURUMKODU), 0) FATDURUMKODU,
  ISNULL(MAX(E.FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU), 0) FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU, 
  ISNULL(MAX(E.FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU), 0) FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU,
  r.datum + @forwardDate  SONGUN,
  datediff(day,@tarih, r.datum + @forwardDate)  as PENDINGDAYS 

from rechhist r  
INNER JOIN KUNDEN K ON K.kdnr = R.kdnr
LEFT OUTER JOIN EFATURAFIRMALARI ON K.afmno = EFATURAFIRMALARI.VKN
LEFT OUTER JOIN EARSIVFATURALOG E ON E.EARCHIVELOGID =
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 EARCHIVELOGID
    FROM EARSIVFATURALOG
    WHERE INVOICEREF = r.REF AND ISVOIDINVOICE = 0
    ORDER BY EARCHIVELOGID DESC
  )
where
E.EARCHIVELOGID IS NOT NULL AND
  (E.CREATEDDATE = @tarih OR
 -- (
 --((E.CREATEDDATE > GETDATE() -7 OR E.FATDURUMKODU != 3 OR E.FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU != 4 OR E.FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU != 1200) AND
 --(E.CREATEDDATE > GETDATE() -7 OR E.FATDURUMKODU != 3 OR E.FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU != 4 OR E.FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU != 1300) AND
 --(E.CREATEDDATE > GETDATE() -7 OR E.FATDURUMKODU != 3 OR E.FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU != 3 OR E.FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU != 1200)))
 -- )
 (E.CREATEDDATE > GETDATE() -7 OR E.FATDURUM = 3) OR
 E.FATDURUM = 4)
  AND 
  r.fisccode IN (select ref from fiscalcd where mpehotel=@mpehotel and code LIKE '3_e-Fat%' )
group by r.ref, r.datum, r.rechnr, r.name, r.resno, r.kdnr, r.sum_belast
```

Here is my timer code:

```
private void timerFaturaGetir_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendStatusMessage("Fatura listesi okunuyor.");
        this.Text = this.Text.Replace(this.Text.Substring(this.Text.Length - 11, 10), DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        timerFaturaGetir.Stop();
        timerFaturaGetir.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            try
            {
                grdProjects.DataSource = null;
                var dbContext = new DbServis();
               
                var result = dbContext.SPSendEFaturaInvoiceToday();
                if (result != null && PendinDateControl == 0)
                {
                    
                    //0 public string Tur { get; set; }
                    //1 public DateTime? Tarih { get; set; }
                    //2 public int FaturaNo { get; set; }
                    //3 public string FaturaUnvani { get; set; }
                    //4 public int Tutar { get; set; }
                    //5 public int Ref { get; set; }
                    //6 public DateTime? GonderimTarihi { get; set; }
                    //7 public DateTime? GonderimSaati { get; set; }
                    //8 public string PDFFatura { get; set; }
                    //9 public int Deneme { get; set; }
                    //10 public string GonderimMesaji { get; set; }
                    //11 public int FATDURUM { get; set; }
                    //12 public int FATDURUMKODU { get; set; }
                    //13 public int FATGONDERIMDURUMUKODU { get; set; }
                    //14 public int FATGONDERIMCEVABIKODU { get; set; }
                    
                    grdProjects.DataSource = result;
                    grdProjects.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                    grdProjects.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                    grdProjects.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh\\:mm";
                    grdProjects.Columns[0].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[1].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[2].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[3].Width = 200;
                    grdProjects.Columns[4].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[5].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[6].Width = 80;
                    grdProjects.Columns[7].Width = 60;
                    grdProjects.Columns[8].Width = 100;
                    grdProjects.Columns[9].Width = 50;
                    grdProjects.Columns[10].Width = 200;

                    var dgwWidth = 15 + 25; // 15 = HScroll kaldırmak için, 25 = RowHeaderWith
                    for (int i = 0; i < grdProjects.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dgwWidth += grdProjects.Columns[i].Width;
                    }
                    grdProjects.Width = dgwWidth + 5;
                    this.Width = dgwWidth + 50; // 50 = Form sağ-sol ayarı
                    grdProjects.ClearSelection();
                }
                else
                {
                  
                    grdProjects.DataSource = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SendStatusMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " :timerFaturaGetir Hata mesajı : " + ex.Message + "\n"
                    + ((ex.InnerException != null) ? "    " + ex.InnerException.Message + "\n" : ""));
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            timerFaturaGetir.Enabled = true;
            timerFaturaGetir.Start();
        }
    }
```

I can display on the grid procedure values but i have to get pendingDays value to check if pendingDays = 0 or not.

Can You please help me about this subject. Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is not only getting the `pendingDays` value. Your sp is too complicated. You need to simplify it. e.g there is a `tarih` variable. Its type is already `datetime`. you are casting it first to `date` and then to `datetime`. And also you have some mistakes in your select query. You have 2 `try` blocks on your application side. Strange approach. **As an answer**, you can filter `pendingDays` control on your sp, and no need to check it on your application side.

Comment: Thanks, i will try in the way that you told.

Comment: After simplifying the sp, edit your question.

Comment: I solved. Thanks you reply.